# Rspec parameters to shared context

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I want to test if the user is logged in,  in each of the controller actions.

What's best practice to DRY this out so that I can repeat it for all my get actions, i.e. get,show, new, edit.

It will require passing in get :index, get :new, etc.  and passing in the parameter for the show and edit.

Here's the non-DRY version with just one action:

```
RSpec.shared_context 'when user is not logged in' do

 before do
    sign_out :user 
  end

  it 'GET#index redirects to sign in page' do   
      get :index       
      expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
```

I want to do this for each of the controller actions without having to copy/paste the code.

I hope this is clear! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly, but I think this should work:

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'when user is not logged in' do |actions|
  before { sign_out :user }

  actions.each do |action|
    it "GET##{action} redirects to sign in page" do   
      get action
      expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end

it_should_behave_like 'when user is not logged in', %i(new index)
```